# launch a subProcess from within Scala application with Jar in the classpath?

Tags: java, scala

looking for a way to launch a subprocess as java -jar ... from within my scala application.

So far the way i do it, is by manually adding the exec jar in my working directory from which my application runs or do a subProcess to donwload it. I use Ammonite Ops to lunch my sub-process. It works fine.

However i was wondering if i could add this jar as a dependency of my application/Project via sbt, and then launch it from within my app. But i have no idea how to launch a jar that has been resolved and which i suspect is added to the classpath ?

Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Does it really have to be a new sub process? Why not just a new thread / future running the main of that other jar?

Comment: Complicated jar, not easy to use.

Comment: But if you want to articulate your solution in a response that would be great. I will try to investigate how to use it that way too

Comment: Among other thing, that program return things i am interested into, with ammonite ops, i can easily get, what comes out of stdout or stderr, and so forth, if i go your way, i would need to go fetch the response of running the main myself in err out, which get mixed up with my own process, while also checking the return status of the main. Lot of thing to deal with

Comment: I just asked because i saw this https://get-coursier.io/docs/cli-launch